# Why don't fire drop event in html5?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I'm using html5 dragndrop native. Every events is fired? but not drop.

```
 $(".dnd").each(function(obj) {
      $(this).attr('draggable', true);
      $(this).on('dragstart', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('dragStart ' + $(this).attr('id'));
        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/data', this,content');
      });

      $(this).on('drop', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('drop ' + $(this).attr('id'));
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/data');
        console.log('data: ' + data);
      });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/owb2n9r7/